# MYSQL Stored Procedure to purge the data for definite period of time

Tags: mysql, purge

Please tell how to create a stored procedure in mysql that will purge the data of table for definite period of time like actual detail for 1 day and history for 3 weeks.

How to create stored procedures

Comment: You need not in stored procedure but in event procedure which starts by schedule (for example, daily) and deletes the rows which matches your purging criteria. See [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). *How to create stored procedures* See [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: I need stored procedure that is required.through stored procedure only.

Comment: No problems, create SP. A link to the documentation is already provided.

Comment: I need sp only that is why I asked the question what logic will be there through sp

Comment: *what logic will be there through sp* SP receives date parameter and deletes the rows which matches this parameter value with one query.

Comment: Can you create one and show with example scenario is we have two tables one is actual and there history maintained in other so for actual we need to have data for 7 days and history we have for 1 month